# IP protecting folder with .htaccess not working

Tags: wordpress, security, .htaccess

I am trying to limit access to my website's wp-admin (I'm using WordPress and http://example.com/wp-admin is the login page for the CMS), e.g. http://example.com/wp-admin to a whitelist of IP addresses. I created a `.htaccess` folder in the `/wp-admin` directory with the following code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

The `x's` above are my IP address which I simply Googled. Why is it that when I upload this `.htaccess` file to the `/wp-admin` directory of my site it's blocking ME from accessing the site's wp-admin?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like http://www.dnsstuff.com/ to find your current IP.

And if it's dynamic, allow a whole block by using i.e., 168.192.1.0/24 rather than allowing  168.192.1.1 to 168.192.1.25 or so individually

And, the block should look like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all

# whitelist IP
allow from 168.912.1.0/24

deny from all
```

Comment: I tried this an the problem still persist. It's locking me out of that directory/page.